# To track status of application running at web server

Tags: java, web-services, web-development-server

I need to track whether the application is running at webserver or NOT. For this i code one java application which sends the http request to server and track whether application is running or NOT based on response. Now i have load balancer which is balancing load among 3 server running same application and i am sending the same request , then how to find out the ip of the machine from which i am getting the response so that i can track whether application is running on that server or not. My application will run in local network where all server are running.
Hopefully i am able to explain my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code performing the check is running in the same local network than the application servers, I suggest you completely by pass the load-balancer for this check and perform your http request directly to the 3 applications servers.

Usually you have two kind of checks :

- one check made in the local production networks (before any loadbalancer, proxy,etc.)
- another one made the Internet to make sure actual users can access the application : this is more an end-to-end check and it will also warns you if your connection, load balancer or any other element is down.

If you really cannot make request to the real application servers, I'm afraid it will generally not be possible : if made properly, load-balancing is normally completely transparent for the http client. You might want to look at [this answer on security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30660/how-do-you-detect-load-balancing) for more details.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. But as per my requirement , i need to hit one url via my java application and request will be send to load balancer first. Then i will get the response . SO rather than hitting each application server directly , i want to pass my request via load balancer. It is requirement.Now how to get ip of that particular  application server from which response is comming.

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve then ? If it's monitoring the application servers, then you should not go through the load balancer, and your requirements might be off (it happens too !)

Comment: requirement is i need to check whether apache server and application in that server is running or not. I was told that i will be given unique requests , and then in report i need to populate the ip of that application server. Is it possible to do it with java application without making any code changes in load balancer or any other server

Comment: No I don't think it is, unless the load balancer is improperly configured and exposes the IP of the application servers behind him.